# What's the prefered way of running batch SQL script from PHP (Kohana) on a Postgres DB

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, kohana, phpunit

I'm setting up Postgres database testing for a Kohana 3.2 project. I would like to create a temporary schema, run several sql scripts from file to establish the schema, and then do my testing and then drop the temporary schema in tearDown.

I've tried getting the contents of the scripts using file_get_contents($sqlfilename) and then using Kohana's DB:query() but that is hack and didn't work properly anyway.

pg_execute will not work because the files are batch scripts

Should I run psql commands with exec()?

What is the best/preferred way of running batch scripts on a Postgres DB from PHP?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pg_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) can run multiple statements:

> #### *query*
>
> > The SQL statement or statements to be executed. When multiple statements are passed to the function, they are automatically executed
> >     as one transaction, unless there are explicit BEGIN/COMMIT commands
> >     included in the query string. However, using multiple transactions in
> >     one function call is not recommended.
> >
> > Data inside the query should be properly escaped.

Thus, a hacky way to run a batch script would be:

```
pg_query($conn, "BEGIN; COMMIT;\n" . file_get_contents($filename));
```

The only correct alternative I can think of would be to run `psql` as an external program:

```
system("psql < " . escapeshellarg($filename));
```

I haven't tested either of these.  Good luck.

Comment: `pg_query($conn, "BEGIN; COMMIT;\n" . file_get_contents($filename));` works great even if it is a bit hacky! thanks!